# Having trouble displaying nested objects in JSON call using Angular

Tags: json, angular

Disclaimer: I am new to Angular :-)

I am experimenting with intertwining Angular and a weather api and I am stumped on how to approach displaying nested data in the JSON payload (Namely, the items under the Historical object). I am able to call and display top level items in the payload.

Here's where I am at:

```
{{ this.weatherData?.current.precip }} <-- this shows the current precipitation successfully
{{ this.weatherData?.historical.maxtemp }} <--- this doesn't display anything
```

My API url: https://api.weatherstack.com/historical?access_key=000000hidden0000000&historical_date=2019-08-30&query=london

API documentation: https://weatherstack.com/documentation

Screen shot of console:
[image]

Many thanks for your coaching and patience that comes with a curious newbie.

Comment: Small correction. My query in the console screen shot was "63129".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The historical data is returned by date, so you would have to do like this to show a single date:

```
{{ this.weatherData?.historical['2018-08-30'].maxtemp }}
```

Or in a loop to show all dates:

```
<div *ngFor="let history of this.weatherData?.historical | keyvalue">
  {{ history.key + ': ' + history.value.maxtemp }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this.weatherData?.historical` is an array with key is as Date. If you are certain that there will only be 1 value in `this.weatherData?.historical` array, you should be able to access it like below:

```
this.weatherData?.historical[0].maxtemp
```

Comment: Thank you both. These responses are quite helpful. This may be a product of my code formatting plugin, but my editor insists on formatting the code like this:

   {{ (this.weatherData?.historical.maxtemp)[0] }}

The parentheses may be throwing it off..?

Comment: Ope. I disabled the code formatting plugin to allow the code to be saved without the parentheses. Now, I am getting a Cannot read property '0' of undefined. It seems the array syntax is not working out.